# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`[City]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to load all cities from cities table and show it in dropdownlist in client side but it shows this error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[EVS.Dotnet277.Entities.City]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'.

### Action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SignUp()
{
    ViewBag.CityList = _userService.GetAllCities();
    return View();
}
```

### html

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="select margin-bottom-15">
@Html.DropDownList("City", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CityList, "- Select City -", new { @class = "form-control"})
/label>
</div>
```

Comment: You obviously, need to convert your DbSet of Cities to a list of SelecLlistItem objects to use them as you are doing in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to this :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SignUp()
{
    ViewBag.CityList =new SelectList( _userService.GetAllCities(),dataValueField, dataTextField);
    return View();
}
```

View Code :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="select margin-bottom-15">
@Html.DropDownList("City", (SelectList)ViewBag.CityList, "- Select City -", new { @class = "form-control"})
/label>
</div>
```